# How to aggregate data in R by a column containing strings?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have data that looks like this:

```
     day            event           id            price  count 
  2017-01-10 viewed product        1234            469     1
  2017-01-10     conversion        1234            559     3
  2017-01-10       checkout        1234            559    13
  2016-11-14     conversion        1234            449     1
  2017-01-09       checkout        1234            559     2
  2017-01-09     conversion        1234            559     1
  2017-01-09 viewed product        1234            559   147
  2016-12-30       checkout        1234            469    65
  2016-11-18 viewed product        1234            389     3
```

What I would like to do is for each unique price get the sum of "viewed product","checkout" and "conversion". So the end result would be something like this:

```
price      viewed product    checkout    conversion
 389           3                0            0
 449           0                0            1  
 469           1                0            0
 559         147               15            4
```

Comment: Whats about simply using `table(d$price, d$event)`?

Comment: That does essentially give me the data I need but I need the columns in that format to add a calculated metric later and then run a regression based on the calculated columns.

Comment: `adf <- aggregate(count ~ event + price, FUN = sum, data = df); reshape(adf, idvar = "price", timevar = "event", direction = "wide")` and `reshape2::dcast(df, price ~ event, value.var = "count", fun.aggregate = sum)` should both work here.

Comment: @nrussell Thanks! the code you pasted works. I'm new to R and didn't know its referred to as reshaping from long to wide.